# Stripe.js with NodeJS: When transferring, what does 'destination' parameter represent?

Tags: javascript, node.js, stripe-payments, fetch, payment

I am looking at the creating a transfer object page (https://stripe.com/docs/api/node#create_transfer), and I am seeing:

```
stripe.transfers.create({
  amount: 400,
  currency: "usd",
  destination: "acct_195VVsIJdBx802Zf"
  description: "Transfer for test@example.com"
}
```

**But what does destination represent and how can I obtain it for debit card transfers?**

And on the tutorial, Stripe is actually suggesting me to create a recipient object first, before transferring (https://stripe.com/docs/sending-transfers):

```
stripe.transfers.create({
  amount: 1000, // amount in cents
  currency: "usd",
  recipient: recipientId,
  card: cardId,
  statement_descriptor: "JULY SALES"
}
```

**In this case, does `cardId` mean the `id` of the card token provided to create the recipient?**

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The `destination` is either (a) the destination Connected Stripe Account (eg. `acc_xxx`) for the funds to be transferred to (minus the Stripe Fee + Application Fee) or (b) the destination External Account (debit cards, bank accounts, etc.) (eg. `ba_xxx`, `card_xxx`, etc.).

You can connect two Stripe Accounts together using Stripe Connect, then transfer money using the Account ID.

Comment: Before I accept the answer and upvote, what do you mean by `ba_xxx`? Is that the debit card number?

Comment: Oh, bank accounts will have an id of ba_xxx; debit cards will have an id of card_xxx (where the xxx represents an alpha-numeric string of random-ish characters).  In this case, your debit card will have an id beginning with the `card_`-prefix.